# Nestjs Deploy on railway giving error but works fine on local machine

Tags: deployment, nestjs, railway

```
    /app/dist/src/patient/patient.controller.js:77
    ﻿__metadata("design:paramtypes", [Request]),
    ﻿^
    ﻿ReferenceError: Request is not defined
    ﻿at Object.<anonymous> (/app/dist/src/patient/patient.controller.js:77:38)
    ﻿at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:14)
    ﻿at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1209:10)
    ﻿at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:32)
    ﻿at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:868:12)
    ﻿at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1057:19)
    ﻿at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    ﻿at Object.<anonymous> (/app/dist/src/patient/patient.module.js:12:30)
    ﻿at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:14)
    ﻿at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1209:10)
    ﻿npm WARN config production Use `--omit=dev` instead.
```

i tried deploying on railway but i keep getting that error which im not getting from my local machine... please help